# Flask WTForms: How to Refresh the Page after Submit

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a page which displays a list of reservation information. There is a sidebar where the users can use to filter particular reservations. One element is a multi-checkbox form where the user can select a number of classrooms.

After the user submits the form, a URL is generated which includes the new filter information and is redirected to the URL.

Form:

```
class MultiCheckboxForm(SelectMultipleField):
    widget = ListWidget(prefix_label=False)
    option_widget = CheckboxInput()

class classroomSidebarForm(FlaskForm):
    classrooms_list = MultiCheckboxForm('Classrooms', coerce=int)
    submit = SubmitField('Submit selection')
```

Blueprint:

```
@resblueprint.route('/<resfilter:res_filter>/', defaults={'page': 1},
                    methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@resblueprint.route('/<resfilter:res_filter>/<int:page>')
def allreservations(res_filter, page):
    '''Display reservations'''

    # code to generate other template parameters

    # code to dynamically generate the choices: classrooms_list

    form = classroomSidebarForm()
    form.classrooms_list.choices = classrooms_list

    if request.method == 'POST':
        selected_classrooms = () 

        if form.classrooms_list.data is not None:
            for selected_classroom_id in form.classrooms_list.data:
                selected_classrooms.append(
                    dict(form.classrooms_list.choices).selected_classroom_id)

        newconds = (res_filter.conds[0], res_filter.conds[1], selected_classrooms, 
                    res_filter.conds[3], res_filter.conds[4], res_filter.conds[5])
        res_filter.conds = newconds
        # the above updates the reservation filter
        # where conds[2] is replaced by the updated list of classrooms

        # then the same page should be rendered again, with the updated res_filter
        # preferably the form is not cleared

    return render_template('reservation/allres.html.j2',
                           res=res,
                           pagination=pagination,
                           res_filter=res_filter,
                           form=form)
```

Sidebar:

```
{% macro desktop_sidebar_res(endpoint, res_filter, form) %}
<div id="sidebar" class="col-md-2">

    # generates the other filter options

    <form action="{{ url_for(endpoint, res_filter=res_filter.to_url()) }}" method="POST">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        {{ form.classrooms_list.label }} {{ form.classrooms_list }}
        {{ form.submit }}
    </form>

    {{ caller and caller() }}
</div>
{% endmacro %}
```

It can be confirmed that `url_for(endpoint, res_filter=res_filter.to_url())` correctly produces the current URL with the current filter information.

The code cannot return the form data back to the blueprint function. The block after `if request.method == 'POST':` cannot be reached. So I suspect there might be something wrong with `action=""`.

After new filter is generated. How would I reload the template?

Tell me if any further clarification is needed.

Comment: I'm working on an existing project. As you can see, I'm an absolute beginner at web development. Any pointers would be welcome!

Comment: Do you have `DEBUG=True` in your Flask code? If this is True, you will get debug information in the console and will help you figure out the problem. If you get an error, please share the Traceback error.

Comment: There is a 418 error. I don't see an error in the uWSGI log or browser console.

Comment: I think you should also have `if request.method=='GET'` to get the form data back.

Comment: instead of `if request.method == 'POST'` try to use `if form.validate_on_submit()` (it will also check csrf)